# 3.5mm PCB mount male plug

Tags: pcb, plug, sourcing

I'm looking for a male 3.5mm audio plug (3 or 4 band) that can be mounted directly to a PCB. Both surface mount and through hole are fine. I'm surprised that all the usual suspects (Digikey, Farnell, Mouser) seem to have nothing like this. Any idea where i could find this?

I could of course take a regular cable mounted plug and bend it etc to fit but i'd prefer a solution that's meant for this purpose at least until proven it's not really possible

Something like this would be ideal (but smaller quantities and preferably not directly from China) [image: 3.5mm PCB plug] (http://plug.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008828495047/pdtl/Phone-jack/1065872532/3.5mm-Male-Plug.htm)

Anybody seen something similar somewhere?

Edit: Preferably horizontal (as in the picture) but vertical might work as well.

Comment: Looks like a part that could be used in several interesting projects. I couldn't find any besides another source of the same kind in China with minimums ~5,000 pcs. Surprisingly specialty. There are some of usual type that screw apart and may be able to be panel mounted of sorts, might work for a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it being sold in china eshops like [this](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/562429941/3_5mm_4_pole_plug_headphone.html) or [this](http://plug.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008828495047/pdtl/Phone-jack/1062483491/3.5mm-4-pole-PCB-Plug.htm)

[image]

Or alternative versions like [this](http://dcplug.en.alibaba.com/product/1332827054-212224684/Easy_solder_to_PCB_3_5mm_TRRS_4_conductors_plug.html)

[image]

Comment: Yes these are exactly what i want, except in quantities of 1-10, not 1000+

Comment: Bottom version looks like [SP-3533-02](https://octopart.com/search?q=SP-3533-02) from CUI. Available in minimum quantities of 1-10 from the usual suspects ;).

Answer (score -1):

Well I have done similar stuff, I used old headphones by removing the plastic/rubber. It might be not exactly look like the image, but able to serve the purpose.